# Why javaBigDecimal2bigDecimal implicit is not applicable?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

With scala 2.9.2 this code:

```
BigDecimal(1) + new java.math.BigDecimal("1")
new java.math.BigDecimal("1") + BigDecimal(1)
```

does not compile because scala.math.BigDecimal$#javaBigDecimal2bigDecimal is not applied in the second case

However, if i define the same implicit right before it, the code compiles:

```
BigDecimal(1) + new java.math.BigDecimal("1")
implicit def javaBigDecimal2bigDecimal(x: java.math.BigDecimal): BigDecimal = BigDecimal(x)
new java.math.BigDecimal("1") + BigDecimal(1)
```

Why so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In first expression `BigDecimal(1) + new java.math.BigDecimal("1")` works rule:

> Compiler will look for implicits defined within any object of the implicit scope of the type it's looking for.

So, there is a method `+(BigDecimal): BigDecimal` on `scala.math.BigDecimal`. Compiler sees wrong argument type (`java.math.BigDecimal`) and starts to look for conversion to type `BigDecimal`. It can't find one in scope, and then it looks in `BigDecimal` object and finds `javaBigDecimal2bigDecimal`.

Second example will work if there is `javaBigDecimal2bigDecimal` conversion in scope because `java.math.BigDecimal` doesn't have `+` method, and compiler will look for conversion to proper type (which has method `+(BigDecimal)`)

Answer (score 3):

Did you `import math.BigDecimal._` ? For my it works just fine:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_04).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import math.BigDecimal._
import math.BigDecimal._

scala> import math.BigDecimal
import math.BigDecimal

scala> BigDecimal(1) + new java.math.BigDecimal(1)
res0: scala.math.BigDecimal = 2
```

edit:

forgot to mention, this works as well:

```
scala> new java.math.BigDecimal("1") + BigDecimal(1)
res0: scala.math.BigDecimal = 2
```

Comment: no, I didn't add the import, but i was wondering why in the first case the implicit is still applicable

Comment: Because in the first case the compiler knows, that a `BigDecimal` is expected and therefore looks in the BigDecimal companion for implicit conversions from the given type to `BigDecimal`